# MySQL full text searching using an index name syntax help needed?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Trying to runa full text search on a table in a modx database,

This works just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM modx_site_content WHERE 
MATCH (`pagetitle`, `longtitle`, `description`, `introtext`, `content`) 
AGAINST ('research' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
LIMIT 10;
```

This gives me an unknown column error:

```
SELECT id, pagetitle FROM modx_site_content WHERE
MATCH (`content_ft_idx`.`content`)  //nor does just (`content_ft_idx`)
AGAINST ('search' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
LIMIT 10;
```

The table index create statement looks like:

```
FULLTEXT INDEX `content_ft_idx` (`pagetitle`, `longtitle`, `description`, `introtext`, `content`)
```

How do I do a full text search on just the 'modx_site_content'.'content' table? or any other combination of tables?

Comment: In `match (list of columnnames)`, the columnnames have to fit to a fulltext index exactly. You cannot use just parts of it or use unindexes columns. (With one exception - MyISAM in boolean mode will not complain about a missing index, but will be as slow as not having an index - because it literally has no index). So add another index with just the one column and use that columnname in the query (without the indexname - just the columnname(s) like in your working query).

Comment: I see - thank you.